# Circuit Scale 0 - 5VDC to 4 - 12VDC using || Opamp noninverting amplifier

Tags: operational-amplifier

I am trying to build a circuit to convert 0 to 5VAC from arduino  to a 4 to 10VDC using LM358N in a close loop noninverting amplifier configuration. This voltage range is required to drive a MOSFET and the reason my lower side is at 4V is because the MOSFET has a Gate threashold voltage of 4. Having a driving circuit of 0 - 10V will only waste my ADC resolution from 0 to 4V.

In my prelim circuit, I have a 358 in non-inverting amplifier configuration with Rsense = 2k and R2 = 1K for Gain 3. Both in my simulation and on my proto, I can see the amplified output however limiting the lower side to 4V is proving to be a bit tricky. I've attached my simulation circuit which is quite similar to the prototype one. [image]

Looking for suggestion on how to modify this circuit so that I can precisely scale 0-5V input to 4-10V output.

PS:

1. My Vdd and Vss for the LM358N are 12V-0V.
2. I've also tried connecting Vss to a 4V supply but that saturated the output at 10V.
3. Ignore the VAC input output in simulation image. This is just for better understanding of the system. The actual signals are VDC.

Comment: The voltage gaim is 3.

Comment: Your MOSFET gate voltage of 4V is a variable parameter - it may be 4.0V on one device, but 3.5V or 4.5V on other devices, even from the same batch.  Consider a servo circuit instead, which means to actually measure the output and use that to adjust the gate voltage.  That way, the variance between devices does not matter.

Comment: @Franc You are right. The gain is actually 3.

Comment: @rdtsc You are right in saying 4V Vth is variable which is why I was planning to use a trim pot on inverting input to fine tune the parameter. Infact my prototype testing suggests Ids in milli amps at 3V Vgs (which could be leakage current). As for the servo circuit, maybe I am lost in traslation but can you please elaborate on it ? I thought the feedback config of the opamp IS adjusting the output .

Comment: Essentially the feedback is from the wrong place and influencing the wrong thing. The choice of 4V will not always be correct. As @rdtsc says, a different circuit topology should be selected.

Comment: This circuit seems dubious. What are you trying to control with the MOSFET? It's true that the OP amp is running closed-loop, but the MOSET is outside the loop. If you insist on trimming Vgs theshold with a potentiometer, you would want a gain of 1.6 (based on your title) or a gain of 1.2 (based on your description) with an offset of +4V in either case.  You are also going to lose a lot of resolution after you pass the Vgs theshhold and the response will certainly not be linear.

Comment: Vgs(th) not only varies from unit-to-unit but it has a significant negative temperature coefficient. A well-designed circuit will accommodate the worst-case limits but will not depend in any way on the exact value.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany This is my first time experimenting with analog circuits and you are absolutely right. I did some experiments last night and the Vgs vs Ids graph given in  the datasheet are complete off from the actual results and as you said, its mose likely due to the temperature coffecient which cannot be raplicatred in real world. Normally in digital circuits, this is not a factor we consider.  I'm glad I didn't finalize my circuit based on simulations and theoratical maths.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a variable DC offset to your DAC output, here provided by R1.

Since you drive a capacitive load, I added a decoupling resistor R4 to ensure stability of the OpAmp. C1 prevents oscillation.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fTgYnZ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

UPDATE

If the MOSFET current must be controlled, a closed loop circuit has many advantages.

- Differences in the threshold voltage are compensated by the control loop.
- The full DAC voltage range is used.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f52QAP.png)</sup>

Comment: This does seem to work in simulation. I will give it a shot on my proto board today and provide feedback. I do however have to modify it such that  the inverting input is connected to the MOSFET low side with a shunt resistor . Can I simply remove the R5 / R6  ? I tried to edit the circuit but the output seem to just saturate to 12V with no control !

Comment: @Prashant To answer this, you should explain what you want to achieve with that circuit. Do you want to create an adjustable current sink?

Comment: Sorry I went on a tangent my my previous question. I guess the basic question I am trying to understand is that when using OPAmp as amplifier, the input signal is amplified to the "bias" voltage applied to Vss and Vee (12V in our case). I've seen examples where this rail is applied +12V and -12V so then why can't I apply +12V and +4V to scale my input ?